# osFileManager which software package should I use?

Tags: apache, xampp, wamp, lamp, wampserver

I need to use osFileManager. SO I need to setup a webserver on Windows. Which package is the best?

The PC will be accessed only on a private LAN.

I've tried downloading Apache, PHP, PHPAdmin and MySQL but had a very hard time configuring and installing the software. So I am looking for an installer that does everything and sets up a server.

There are several packages WAMP, XAMP, LAMP and all sound great but I needed the best one for this specific open source project.

I am also willing to use a clone. The whole purpose is to upload a file (replace the existing one) on a weekly basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend XAMPP.  It took a few times for me to configure it properly.
Write down everything.  The latest package is pretty quickly configured.

Other tips:

- Save a virgin image of the webserver
- Save a virgin image of your Windows box
- Make backups along the way..for instance use something like Oracle Virtual Box to get it configured in a Windows XP environment.  If you have an OEM product key, you may be able to use it in a Virtual Machine, however I'm unsure.  A professional license will be usable in a VM.

Comment: I downloaded XAMPP and I keep getting error messages saying php5ts.dll failed to load. I made sure that the file is there. Googled and followed their advice. I performed an uninstall then installed it again. Apache won't load. What version of XAMPP are you using? Or How can I fix this? I downloaded 1.8

Comment: Have you uninstalled all versions of PHP, Perl, MySQL, etc before installing XAMP?  It should be able to run independently but there will be problems with what ports are used.  Sorry for the late reply.